# Passing html5 elements values to servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

If I manage to design a html5 web page, and there if I have a radio button, a check box or a text box, can I pass these values to a servlet upon the click of a submit button?

I know how to do all these in normal html now. I want to use html5 so that it all looks beautiful.

Comment: Can you please put some code here of what you have until now?

Answer (score 1):

> If I manage to design a html5 web page, and there if I have a radio button, a check box or a text box, can I pass these values to a servlet upon the click of a submit button?
>
> I know how to do all these in normal html now.

HTML 5 is still normal HTML. Everything still works in the same way. Some things have new options. There are some new things.

So: Yes.

> I want to use html5 so that it all looks beautiful.

HTML 5 adds nothing beauty related to the language.

Comment: I am not quite sure if this is an answer. Perhaps better off as a comment?

Comment: Edited to make the answer explicit (instead of implicit by the explanation for why it was the answer).